# AngularJS javascript filter less than

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm needing to filter a collection of items that are due YTD and it seems there should be an easy way to do this without writing a special function (no matter how small).

```
$scope.filtered_incidents = $filter('filter')($scope.incidents, {due_month: index});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks!  You put me on the right track.  This is what I came up with.

```
$scope.filtered_incidents = $filter('filter')($scope.incidents, {due_month: index},function(actual,expected){if(actual != '' && actual <= expected)return true;return false});
```

Comment: In your question, you explicitly said "without writing a special function (no matter how small)", that's why I didn't use the "comparator" in my answer.

Comment: I was trying to stay away from writing a function for the whole filter.  I didn't know about the comparator parameter or how to use it.

Comment: well, I'm glad that the comment of my answer leaded you to the right direction.